# Не получается сделать корректный HTTP запрос

Tags: http, post, rest

Всем здравствуйте!
Я делаю клиентскую часть RestAPI приложения на Android. Разобрался я с GET запросами, получаю что нужно - вывожу на экран. Но когда пришло время сделать POST запрос на регистрацию пользователя - никак не могу получить ответ от сервера 200... Скорее всего я что-то не так делаю при построении самого запроса. Так как же нужно построить запрос для регистрации нового пользователя? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Описание:
Модель пользователя:
• Id — идентификатор пользователя
• Username — имя пользователя.
• Password — пароль.

Для выполнения запросов к api нужно передавать полученный токен доступа в заголовке http-запроса:

Authorization: Token token>

POST /api/register/ — зарегистрировать пользователя.
Пример запроса:
{
"username": ,
"password": 
}
Пример ответа:
{
"success": true,
"token": token>
}

Comment: json надо посылать в body а не то что вы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставте в Body 
`{ "username":"zruko" ,"password":"pass2" }`

Comment: К сожалению:[https://pp.vk.me/c638527/v638527766/1d9f1/iNZhMabtjKI.jpg]

Comment: BogdanK, вы не знаете что за тип данных в json который записывается в <>? [https://pp.vk.me/c638527/v638527766/1d9f8/tL91E61nZ-o.jpg ]

Comment: Строка, она должна быть в `"`

Answer (score 1):

Странно, но когда я сделал тот же запрос в Postman, а не в Fiddler - все заработало.
Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: да, параметры `POST` запроса можна передать через `&` _(как аргументы в `GET`)_ но это не всегда будет работать, сервер может бросать ошибку ну и это будет не правильно, для этого он и есть `POST` чтобы передавать в теле даные